# Group By Two columns and Get Last Value in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a list of object. I want to group this list from two columns and get the last value of this column.

I also want to have the entire copy of the object.

I have write this code:

```
var FileDaInviare = info.FNAVB00R.ToList();
var FileDaInvNew = from c in FileDaInviare
                   group c by new
                   {
                      c.Progressivo_Gemap,
                      c.Committente_Gemap,
                   } into gcs
                   select new FNAVB00R()
                   {

                   };
                   FileDaInvNew = FileDaInvNew.ToList();
```

But with this code i have only the first value of the group by(I want the last) and the object is empty. I want copy of the entire object directly please consists of hundred columns.

Thanks to all

Comment: Use `gcs.Last()` to get the last row in the grouping set.

Comment: You use an empty constructor and don't initialize `FNAVB00R`, so you actually don't have anything from the two columns but only the right count.

Comment: "I want to group... I want the entire object..." - surely these requirements are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Last` extension method.

```
FileDaInvNew = FileDaInviare.GroupBy(g=> new {g.Progressivo_Gemap, g.Committente_Gemap})
             .Select(x=>x.Last())
             .ToList()
```

Comment: try orderby desending